# What is `wholemeal` in functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming

Can anybody give a clear explanation? What is a *wholemeal programming* in functional programming area. All I've found is that *wholemeal* is a

> focusing on entire data structures rather than their elements

but how can it be archived? 
(Code examples in such languages as Scala or Ocaml are very desirable.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "Functional languages excel at wholemeal programming, a term coined by
>   Geraint Jones. Wholemeal programming means to think big: work with an
>   entire list, rather than a sequence of elements; develop a solution
>   space, rather than an individual solution; imagine a graph, rather
>   than a single path. The wholemeal approach often offers new insights
>   or provides new perspectives on a given problem. It is nicely
>   complemented by the idea of projective programming: first solve a more
>   general problem, then extract the interesting bits and pieces by
>   transforming the general program into more specialised ones."

I also found this

> it helps prevent a disease called "indexitis" and encourages lawful
>   program construction (from "Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design",
>   Richard Bird, 2010)

See also (http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/ICFP09.pdf)

Comment: Am I correctly understand that this is closely similar to `dynamic programming` concept?

Comment: @om: I don't think so. `dynamic` refers to your overall programming style whereas `wholemeal` refers to data structures.

Comment: @0A0D "dynamic programming" usually refers to a variant of divide-and-conquer where subproblems overlap, e.g. Levenshtein edit distance.

Answer (score 5):

I always found the Hutton/Bird Sudoku solver a good example of wholemeal programming: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/sudoku.lhs

A fair number of functional pearls (both that in Bird's excellent book that Code Monkey cites and those available here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Research_papers/Functional_pearls) will probably also be instructive.