# Format text with sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed, tr

Am trying to format the below actual output to get in the same line for each disks

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>
   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1
   /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>
   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1
   /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>
   /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0
   /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>
   /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0
   /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk
```

Trying to get the expected output like below,

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci108e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk|
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci108e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

I tried with below,

```
cat actual_output | tr -s " " | tr "\n" "|"
```

Which is resulting all in single line,

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Micron_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci108e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk|3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Micron_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci108e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

Now need to replace 0. until next 1. contents with newline(\n), so that will get expected result.
Do we have any regex to do the same?

TIA

Comment: last 2 devices have input string of `pci08e` but expected output is showing `pci108e` ... `08` vs `108` ...  typo?

Comment: FYI [according to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832333/format-text-with-sed-or-awk#comment133764639_75832888) there actually aren't always 3 lines per record.

Comment: Do you REALLY want a `|` stuck on the end of every output line?

Comment: No need to have "|" at the end of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying one data set to have only 2 lines:

```
$ cat disk.dat
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>
   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1
   /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>
   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1
   /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>
   /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>
   /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0
   /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk
```

Extending OP's current code:

```
cat disk.dat | tr -s " " | tr "\n" "|" | sed -E "s/\|([0-9])/\|\n\1/g; s/$/\n/"
```

Where:

- the 1st half of the `sed` script places a `\n` between a pipe (`|`) and a number (`[0-9]`)
- the 2nd half of the `sed` script adds a `\n` at the end of the line

An alternative `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'.' '                                        # input field delimiter is a period
           { sub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",$1) }           # remove leading white space from 1st field
($1+0)==$1 { if (NR>1) print ""; pfx="" }          # if 1st field is numeric; if beyond 1st row then terminate previous line of output; reset prefix to empty string
           { printf "%s%s|", pfx, $0; pfx=" " }    # print prefix plus current line; reset prefix to a single space
END        { if (NR>=1) print "" }                 # if we had at least one row of input then terminate previous line of output
' disk.dat
```

Both of these generate:

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0|
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

Answer (score 4):

[`paste`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) in serial mode could work if it is always 3 lines per group:

```
paste -sd'||\n'
```

Output:

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>|   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1|   /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>|   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1|   /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>|   /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0|   /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>|   /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0|   /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk
```

Comment: pipe to `tr -s ' '` to squeeze the whitespace

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk and not relying on there being 3 lines per input record:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/{ if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$0; next} {sub(/ */,"| "); rec=rec $0} END{print rec}' file
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk
```

If you really do want a `|` added the the end of every output line then just change each `print rec` to `print rec"|"`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^\s/{r=r "| " $0;next} NR!=1{print r "|"} {r=$0} END{print r "|"}' data.txt
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>|    /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1|    /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>|    /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1|    /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>|    /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0|    /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk|
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>|    /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0|    /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -zE 's/\n\s+/| /g;s/(\n|$)/|&/g' data.txt
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk|
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

`-z` to process the whole input as a single line, `-E` for extended regex. `s/\n\s+/| /g` to replace newlines followed by one or more spaces by `|` . `s/(\n|$)/|&/g` to insert a `|` before all remaining newlines or the end of file.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in shown samples only.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]+\\.' -v OFS="| " '
rt{
  sub(/^\n/,"",RT)
  $1=$1
  print rt " " $0,_
}
{ rt=RT }
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/([0-9]+\.[^\n]*)\n +/\1| /;ta;s/\n|$/|&/g' input_file
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk|
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\S/{:a;x;1!s/\n(\s)+|$/|\2/gp;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

There will be two conditions; where a line does not start with spaces or it does.

If a line does not begin with spaces (new record):

1. Switch to the hold space
2. If it is not the first line, replace all newlines (followed by spaces) with `|`  and print the result.
3. Delete the result.

If the line starts with spaces (mid record):

1. Append the current line to the hold space
2. Delete the line if it is not the last line
3. Otherwise, jump back and process as if it were a new record.

N.B. That each time a new record is encountered, the previously stored record is processed and printed. Also the symmetry between first and last and  the asymmetry of the use of `x` and `H`.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -zE 's/\n\s+/| /g;s/.*/&|/gm' file
```

N.B. A good example of [wholemeal programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957270/what-is-wholemeal-in-functional-programming). The first substitution reduces all lines to separate records. The second substitution appends `|` to each record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk with modulo operator. In a condition: if the current line is not divisible by 3 then the pipe symbol "|" is added, otherwise the new line is added:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS=""; }{printf "%s%s", $0,(NR%3?"|":"\n");}' actual_output
```

Comment: Sometimes, Output may not contain 3 lines in a group. It may be 2 or 3 and the only common thing I found is the starting number pattern like "0." or "1." or "2."

Comment: @user3132525 you've GOT to show stuff like that in the sample input/output in your question as it's a huge detail that greatly impacts potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is always Perl:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'for $_ (split(/(?<!\A)(?=^\d+\.\h+)/m)) {s/\R\h*/| /g; say}' file
```

Or an awk:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+\.[ \t]+/{
    if (s) print s
    s=$0 "|"
    next
}
{sub(/^[ \t]+/," ")
s=s $0 "|"
}
END{print s}
' file
```

Either prints:

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk| 
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk| 
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk| 
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk|
```

Answer (score 0):

with ***ANY*** `awk` :

> ```
> awk 'ORS = NR % 3 ? "|" : "\n"'
> ```

```
0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>|   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1|   /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>|   /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1|   /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>|   /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0|   /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>|   /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0|   /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    /^[0-9]*\./{
        printf "%s|", (NR==1 ? $0 : "\n"$0); next
    }
    {
        sub(/^ */," "); printf "%s|", $0
    }
    END{printf "\n"}
' file

0. ct1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347c@4/e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk|
1. c2t1d0 <INTEL-ADDPF2KX076T9S-2CV1-6.19TB>| /pci@4,0/pci8086,347d@5/apci108e,487c@0/disk@1| /dev/chassis/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk|
2. c3t0d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MAAAD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci8e,4872@17/disk@0,0| /dev/chassis/MB/SSDR0/SSD0/disk|
3. c4t2d0 <ATA-Min_5300_MTFD-D3MU-223.57GB>| /pci@0,0/pci08e,4872@17/disk@2,0| /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/SSDR0/SSD1/disK|
```